# Getting error on creating foreign key (error cide : 1005)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

Here table SEARCHAUTHOR refrying CATALOGUEBASE but the code results in following  error:

`Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'easylibdb1.SEARCHAUTHOR' (errno: 150)`

Table structure of `CATALOGUEBASE` TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CATALOGUEBASE(

        ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        TITLE VARCHAR(250),
        SUBTITLE VARCHAR(250),
        AUTHOR VARCHAR(100),
        EDITION VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '',
        TITLENUMBER VARCHAR(500),
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
```

and `SEARCHAUTHOR`  TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SEARCHAUTHOR(

        ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        TITLENUMBER VARCHAR(500),
        AUTHOR VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '',
        SEQUENCE INT UNSIGNED,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (TITLENUMBER) REFERENCES CATALOGUEBASE (TITLENUMBER)        
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the shouting.

Comment: @L-Three : error cide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Foreign key must be index in mysql.**

InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CATALOGUEBASE(

    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TITLE VARCHAR(250),
    SUBTITLE VARCHAR(250),
    AUTHOR VARCHAR(100),
    EDITION VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '',
    TITLENUMBER varchar(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    INDEX(TITLENUMBER)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SEARCHAUTHOR(

    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TITLENUMBER varchar(200),
    AUTHOR VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '',
    SEQUENCE INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TITLENUMBER) REFERENCES CATALOGUEBASE(TITLENUMBER)        
);
```

this Query is working. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea4d3)